# What is the best way to update default CKEditor plugin code to add custom features?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to add custom functionality to default CKEditor features, for example:

- Add a new option in "Link Type" picklist in Link overlay in addition to existing "URL" and "E-mail" options. This new option will be used to generate links specific to an organization using an ID.

How can I achieve above goal while keeping the CKEditor code maintainable? i.e I should be able to upgrade CKEditor to newer versions without having to reapply all custom code changes again.

I am using CKEditor version **4.5.10** (dev)